# C#: Form width used in class does not refresh when form resized

Tags: c#, forms, class, refresh

I am working on some school work and I am wondering if you could solve this.
I got my form.cs code and my class apple.cs(some snake fruit generation)
I choosed that my apple is being randomly spawned accros the form width/height, but when I resize that form, It keeps to spawn within old "borders" of the form.

Can I reload it somehow?

```
 class Apple    {
    Random nc = new Random();
    Form1 hl;
    //Properties
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public Size Size { get; set; }
    public Point Pt { get; set; }
    //constructors
    public Apple()
    {
        hl = new Form1();
        int s = 10;
        this.Color = Color.Red;
        this.Size = new Size(s,s);
        this.Pt = new Point(nc.Next(s,hl.panel1.Width-(2*s-1)),nc.Next(s,hl.panel1.Height-(2*s-1)));
    }
    //methods
    public void drawOutPoint(Graphics kp)
    {
        kp.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color), new Rectangle(Bod, Size));
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or you can try this

```
public Apple(double width,double height)
{
\\your code and assign the values 
}
```

and in the form you define the object

```
apple ap=new applw(this.width,this.height);
```

Comment: Thanks youre the best :) !

Answer (score 0):

let the apple get the width and high from the form using

```
double width= this.width;
```

and the same for high

Comment: Did not I do that ? Can you please explain a bit more :) ?

Comment: sorry i hit post accidentally i edited the post you can get it form what I see by to methods one by creating object from the form tow by make function and call it from the form and give it the arguments width and hight

Comment: Maybe it is too much but do you think it is possible to type it for me ?:D I am not advanced programmer and this is kind of confusing to me :) sorry

Comment: this comment is not what you looking for see the other one sorry for being confusing

Comment: I sorry I am not that advanced too but I just shared what I think that It would be helpful ideas